How to view the image that is in the wwwroot of the asp.net core api over the internet
I created an asp.net core api that some of the payload accepts images.
These images are stored in wwwroot/image of the application's folder, and the absolute path is stored in the database.
When testing locally, I can access the image from the path and see the image. I finally deployed to the host using Plesk and can no longer get the images.
A sample response carrying returning images:
{
  "responseCode": "00",
  "responseMessage": "sucessfull",
  "response": {
    "examinationBodies": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Jamb",
        "description": "Joint Admission Matriculation Board",
        "imageUrl": "C:\\Users\\**********\\source\\repos\\Rikudouensof\\AinsExaminations\\AinsExaminations.Api\\wwwroot\\Images/ExaminationBodies\\Jamb.jpeg"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "WAEC",
        "description": "The West African Examination Council",
        "imageUrl": "https://api.ainsexamination.com\\wwwroot\\Images/ExaminationBodies\\WAEC.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Below are the sample results on a .net maui application

I have gone to Plesk and gone to the folder, I have tried to see if I need to give permission. All permission has been given. still no hope.
Kindly help

resolve the image path, and append current Url to the imageUrl to have something like like https://api.ainsexamination.com/Images/ExaminationBodies/WAEC.jpg

Thanks @iSR5 for commenting.
This domain is currently running., as you can see, that URL is not working

Ensure you added UseStaticFiles to your app services.

Alright let me do that right away

It works! @iSR5, thanks a bunch

could you please add a new answer with how you solved it? Then  just mark your answer as answered. This would help others as well (Even for future references). Thank you

Thanks to @iSR5, I found a way to solve it.
Like he commented, the

Ensure you added UseStaticFiles to your app services.

I went to the Program.cs of the API, and added the following line of code;
app.UseStaticFiles();

Please note that this is a .Net core 8 API.

